# Permission to read /var/log/ files on separate system (Chrome OS Linux terminal)

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, root, non-root-user, chrome-os

I need to access two drives which won't boot to their original systems (Raspberry Pi OS on SD card & Ubuntu 20.04 on HDD). As both of these devices are (mostly) inaccessible, my only option is to use the Linux terminal on my Chromebook to copy/read these files. I was able to boot into emergency mode on the Pi, but that doesn't help me to copy them and the Ubuntu drive is completely inaccessible on it's machine.

I was able to access the `/var/log` directory on the Chromebook, but do not have permission to read the files. I have not attempted the Ubuntu drive yet.

How do I gain root permissions on a separate device? Is it even possible? Obviously I have the root password.

Comment: I just realized that an easy solution for the Pi would be using the cp command in emergency mode to a usb thumb drive. Though I don't know if I can mount a drive in emergency mode.

Comment: Easiest way to access the HDD of the Ubuntu would be booting with a Live Linux USB. If the drive is accessible, it can be mounted and you can access the file system. You should be able to copy any important data out from it. RasPi's SD card would be easiest to access from a system with an SD card reader.

Comment: That's a solid point about the Pi. I could pop it into my phone or a tablet, though the Chromebook is an ARM device so I'm not sure it would be much different. I can see the files, I just can't read them.

Comment: I will give the Ubuntu recommendation a try as well.

Comment: Nah - binaries and libraries won't work on a different architecture, but data files are entirely CPU-agnostic :-) You need to mount the drive. When you sudo su to make yourself root, you should be able to copy anything out of the SD card. Same goes for accessing the Ubuntu's drives with a live distro.